# auto adjust custom UITableViewCell and Label in it to the text

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uilabel

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that only has one Label in it. I also set number of lines in Interface Builder to 0 as I read on StackOverflow.

```
import UIKit

class CommonListViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var background: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "roboto", size: titleLabel.font.pointSize)
        NSLog("CommonListViewCell font changed")
    }    
}
```

Here's the view controller's part to work with `UITableView`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.lvMain.delegate = self;
    self.lvMain.dataSource = self;
    self.lvMain.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CommonListViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "commonlistidentifier")
    self.lvMain.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    self.lvMain.rowHeight =    UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commonlistidentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommonListViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.titleLabel?.text = prayerList[indexPath.row].name
    cell.titleLabel?.sizeToFit()
    setLabelFont(cell.titleLabel!)
    Utils.nightCheck([cell.titleLabel!])
    return cell
}
```

So, `.sizeToFit()` doesn't change anything—it still ellipsize the text on 1 line, and I need the label to be as many lines as it needed, and the size of the cell also be fitting for the label.

Comment: Can you put screenshot of label ? What do you want to achieve and what is coming ?

Comment: did you set auto layout contraints on all sides of your label? And do not set a constraint height on your label.

Comment: @Jecky I want if a text is 4 lines - to see it all and the Cell be as high as Label's text needs it and if it's 1 line - be 1 line high. Now it's 1 line and line is ellpsized with ".." at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use self sizing cells.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
 tableView.rowHeight =    UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

In your storyboard or xib you have to make sure that you set proper constraints in your cells.
Do not set a predefined height constraint in your label. Just make sure you give top and bottom constraints. If you are not sure about the text , you can also give a minimum height constraint to the label.

Comment: doesn't help me. The label only has margin constraints .

Comment: @user2976267  Did you try making it self sizing and then you have to make sure that there is bottom constraint to the botttom of the cell

Comment: how do I make it self sizing? I'm new to iOS. Yes, there is bottom constraint. Also, label is 0 lines in IB

Comment: Add the tableview code in the answer to your viewDidLoad  , this tells the tableview to not to look for constant height from delegate rather determine the size dynamically depending on the constraints

Comment: I edited post, take a look at ViewController part . It still doesn't help me

Comment: There is no use of sizeToFit in this scenario. But i think the real problem lies with how you have added your constraints. Try adding all margins constraints-top, bottom, leading ,trailing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126516/discussion-between-user2976267-and-jatin-kumar-malana).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**

**Note:** Both method should work.Tested in Swift 3.

**Method 1:**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // standard tableViewCell height
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

return yourArrayName.count
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

**Note:** You need to put this code inside your cellForRowAt

```
 yourCellName.sizeToFit()
 cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

Output:

[image]