# Swift how to proper update UITableViewCell constraint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, constraints

I wonder how I proper update a tableviewcell constraint?

In my app I am checking if the user is using a iphone 6/7 or iphone 6/7 Plus and depening on that I have to change some constraints.

I have made a subclass of UITableViewCell like this:

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

}
```

Should I change constraints in `prepareForReuse()` or in another method?

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        myConstraint.constant = someNewVal
    }
```

Comment: Your post not very clear what you trying to achieve . if you want to change constrains depends on 6/7+ how about other models.If you want your content size fits to all device.you need a different approach check this like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216729/auto-adjust-custom-uitableviewcell-and-label-in-it-to-the-text/40221431#40221431

Comment: @Joe Sorry for my bad answer. I have some contraints setup for my tableviewCell and I wonder in what method I should change constraints

Comment: Try this.manually setup constrains for leading and trailing space for your label.done set any constrains for width. This will give a dynamic height and set up a width programmically according to size of device.this is the easy way to fix your problem.somewhere you have set your cell.textlabel.numberOfLines = 0  and cell.sizeToFit().let me know this works...

Comment: Try to set your label to scaleAspectFill this will give a dynamic width..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs about `prepareForReuse`:

> If a UITableViewCell object is reusable—that is, it has a reuse identifier—this method is invoked just before the object is returned from the UITableView method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:. For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and selection state. The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when reusing a cell. If the cell object does not have an associated reuse identifier, this method is not called. If you override this method, you must be sure to invoke the superclass implementation.

Therefore, you can use `prepareForReuse`, but due to performance reasons, it would be better to use `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
.

If I understood the docs, `prepareForReuse` should be as fast as possible so `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` would be fast as well. So, it would be better to change the constraints in another method (`tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
)