# Label width shrinks when UITableViewCell is scrolled off & on screen

Tags: swift, uitableview, uilabel, width

A curious re-sizing/narrowing of label widths inside UITableViewCells is happening when I repeatedly scroll cells off by two-cells height and then into view again (image below).

By using

```
label.sizeToFit()
```

in Swift within the cell's class, called right after I assign a string to the label.text property, the widths are perfect and anchored nicely in top-left regardless of whether there is one or two lines of text in the label (I've tried various autoresizing settings in the interface builder.  None seem to have an impact, I'm assuming because sizeToFit overrides them).

What is strange is that when I scroll the tableView up and down, the cells that are off-screen re-load with compressed widths, spilling text onto more lines than they should need.  Any thoughts on why this is happening & why the approach above doesn't seem to work when cells are scrolled?[image]

Also - I can do a work-around by setting a textView with left orientation, disabling any user interaction, then putting my static text in this textView.  I know this is a lazy hack, but is there strong reason why I wouldn't do this?

Comment: no need to call `label.sizeToFit()`, If you are worry about resizing with multi-line just use `label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = ScreenWidth - fixed_widths_of_other_labels`. Anyway you shouldn't call `sizeToFit`

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216729/auto-adjust-custom-uitableviewcell-and-label-in-it-to-the-text/40221431#40221431 may helps...

Comment: Thanks, Joe, this resized my width, but it seems to see two lines of text I need to set the height bigger.  Previously sizeToFit would expand or contract the label's height as needed by the text size (although it re-set in weird ways after being scrolled in & out).

Comment: Try label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true this will give dynamic font size to fit your content.see that works for you...