# UITableview Height set according to cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have `UITableView` in `UIViewController` in this view controller total 3 tableview or 2 `UICollectionView`. so in this one tableview contain many cells or cells data are not static its dynamic according to server. So, I create the table view height outlet & its set on `cellforrowatindex` function of tableview.

So, we use to set height `tableview_height.constant=tableview_height.constant+cell.frame.size.height` using this code my problem showing whitespace on the end of `UITableViewCell`. If I increase the cell then cell are cut from the bottom. I am giving below constraint show in the pic.

[image]

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 7 and above check `uitableviewautodimension`

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216729/auto-adjust-custom-uitableviewcell-and-label-in-it-to-the-text/40221431#40221431

Comment: I am also using uitableviewautodimension @vinodh

Comment: not work by this its increase the cell height its not increase table view height

Comment: are you repeating tableview is staorybaord

Comment: yes i am using this table view for showing one api data

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell

{
    if indexPath.row == 0
    {
        tableview_height.constant = 0
        tableview_height.constant=tableview_height.constant+cell.frame.size.height
    }
    else
    {
        tableview_height.constant=tableview_height.constant+cell.frame.size.height
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: cell height is not fix its increase according to label text

Comment: not working bro by using this its show only two cell & second cell also cut from bottom.

Comment: use this tableview header ?

Comment: tableview_height.estimatedRowHeight = 140
   tableview_height.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension.  i am also using this for increase the cell height.

Comment: how to use in viewForHeaderInSection pls explain

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer on the almost same question.

[How to increase the height of parent view according to height of UITableView in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48825946/how-to-increase-the-height-of-parent-view-according-to-height-of-uitableview-in/48827801#48827801)

It is the best way to achieve what you want, because it does not depend on your table settings or if you have header/footer/custom insets/whatever.

Hope it will help.