# How to increase the height of parent view according to height of UITableView in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have below hierarchy of my screen.

```
-ScrollView 
 -ContentView
   -View1
   -View2
   -View3
   -Collectioview
     -CollectioviewCell 
       -Tableview 
         -Tableviewcell 
            -Content
```

Now here my content of tableview is dynamic so height of tableview cell can't be static.So height of tableview will increase according to number of cell & height of each cell.

Based on Tableview height, Height of collection view should increase which results in increase in height of scroll view content view.

But I am not able to understand how should achieve this with less code? 
or can it be done programatically ?

[image]

Comment: This will help you https://www.printfriendly.com/print?customCSSURL=&disableClickToDel=0&disableEmail=0&disablePDF=0&disablePrint=0&headerImageUrl=&headerTagline=&imageDisplayStyle=right&imagesSize=full-size&source=cs&url_s=uGGCF_%7E_PdN_%7E_PcS_%7E_PcSCBFFvoyrzBovyrmpBz_%7E_PcScabg_%7E_PcSac_%7E_PcSFvMvAt-HvpByyrpGvBAIvrJpryy-svG-zHyGvyvAr-Hvynory_%7E_PcS

Comment: through delegates... maybe... but the entire concept seems quite odd.

Comment: Mee too. Can you tell me the best work around

Answer (score 4):

The most universal way is to observe `contentSize` property of your scroll-/table-/collectionView and to change size accordingly.

To achieve this you should:

> **Note**: examples will be for UIScrollView, but it can be applied for any collectionView

- add observer to your view

  ```
  scrollViewToObserveSizeOf.addObserver(observerObject, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: [.old, .new], context: nil)
  ```
- override `observeValue` method

  ```
  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
      if let scrollView = object as? UIScrollView,
          scrollView == scrollViewToObserveSizeOf,
          keyPath == "contentSize" {
          // Do whatever you want with size
          // You can get new size from scrollView.contentSize
          // or change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? CGSize for new value
          // and change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.oldKey] as? CGSize for old value
          //
          // ! Do not force unwrap this values, just never use force unwrap, 
          // everything could happen
      } else {
          // ! Do not forget to call super.observeValue(forKeyPath:of:change:context) 
          // if it is not object you added observer to
          super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
      }
  }
  ```

To apply it, for example, to UITableView just check if object in `observeValue` method is of `UITableView` type.

This method is called whenever content size of your collection view is changed and you do not need to know anything about if your view has finished loading or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose each row in your table view has fixed height.

So height of table view would be number of row in tableview * height of row. Suppose **hight of each row is 30** and there are **4 rows in table** view then,

```
tableHeight = 4*30 = 120
```

**You don't have to wait for tableview to reload data**. You can **use the count of your array** from which you fill your data in tableview to get number of rows. So your number of rows would be your array's count.
Till here you got the height of your tableview. Now to increase the parent height, Give fixed height to the tableview and collectionview and take a **outlet of height constraint** of both.

Just calculate the height of tableview before reloading and give that height to tableView's height constraint. Also give the same height plus heigh of extra space(If any) to collectionView's height constraint.

For eg :
`tableViewHieghtConstraint.constant = tableHeight`
`collectionViewHieghtConstraint.constant = tableHeight`

This will increase your collectionview's and tableView's height and thus result in increasing the height of your content view.

If you want to calculate the height of your tableview with dynamic height of each cell, following method can be used to get height. **Though this is not recommended and does not work in every case so use this with your own consent.**

```
func reloadData() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        let tableHeight: CGFloat = 0
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.3) {
            for i in 0...aryData.count - 1 {
                let frame = self.tableView.rectForRow(at: IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
                tableHeight += frame.size.height
                print(frame.size.height)
            }
        }
        tableViewHieghtConstraint.constant = tableHeight 
        collectionViewHieghtConstraint.constant = tableHeight
    }
```

You can avoid using delay or provide less delay. Delay is given here in case if there is large amount of data to be processed and displayed on table view then it might take some fraction of seconds.

**P.S: Don't forget to give bottom constraint of collectionview to contentview.**

Comment: I don't know when tableview finished loading as no callback for this and after that get it's height & set height of collection view. Please me at which block of code I should set height of collection view.

Comment: @Techiee Also added a workaround for dynamic height calculation. Please refer my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through following steps:

1. Set row height as automatic for UITableView :

   `self.tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
2. Similarly for collection view, if you haven't managed the size of the cell you can refer: https://medium.com/@wasinwiwongsak/uicollectionview-with-autosizing-cell-using-autolayout-in-ios-9-10-84ab5cdf35a2
3. Now create height constraint for ContentView and set its value as:

   contentViewHieghtConstraint.constant = collectionView.contentSize.height

This will solve your problem.

But your current controls setup seems very clumsy, I suggest you should go with any other approach to set up fewer controls in single view controller if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `UITableView` property `intrinsicContentSize` and return `contentSize` there. Then when you have some changes in table view content size, just call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()` to relayout

YourCustomTableView:

`override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize { return contentSize }`

YourViewController or code where you handle layout:

`func refreshViewController() {
  // do some stuff with your custom table view
  yourCustomTableView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}`

Answer (score 0):

change you hierarchy,this is not a good idea, but it works

```
-CollectionView 
  -CollectioviewCell
  -CollectioviewCell
  -CollectioviewCell
  -CollectioviewCell
    -Collectioview
      -CollectioviewCell 
        -Tableview 
          -Tableviewcell 
             -Content
```